Creating GraphQL query consisting various entities using neo4j-graphql-java
I am trying to build and application using the example - Neo4j GraphQl Java Spring Boot Example
I have Neo4j Database in which there are various node types like Fruit, Sweet, Vegetable. I have defined their schema in neo4j.graphql file. and while running graphiql on browser, I can directly query these nodes with conditions.
For example :-
  fruits{
    name
    quantity
  }
 }

This query gives me the fruit nodes with the mentioned fields.
I can query the individual entities but I want to get these entities under one name/query.
I have tried defining the following in no4j.graphql
 type Query {
      getItems: [Item]
   }
   
  type Item{
     fruits: [Fruit]
     vegetables: [Vegetable]
     sweets: [Sweet]
     }

But this is not working.
